# .htaccess add at this (?image=1) and end of every url of my site

Tags: .htaccess

i have a site and a wordpress site so i like to every url to add **?image1** at end

example:

mywp.com/**?image1**    mywp.com/category/sport/**?image1** mywp.com/post/123/**?image1**

mysite.com/**?image=1**   mysite.com/123.html/**?image1**

so i like page to be the same but to add at end this **?image1**
so is same as going to any page and paste this **?image1**  at end of url

i found this on google try it but this dont work

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(([\w/-]+)?[\w-])/?(?!:\?image1)$ http://domain.com/$?image1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(([\w/-]+)?[\w-])\?image1$ test/index.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert this rule **just before main WP routing rule**:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)image1(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}?image1 [L,QSA,R=302,NE]
```

Comment: see this site. http://goo.gl/npxJqX  in every page and homepage it add this ?83b24507e7210585d61af70bf7ea4fc2   at the end

in my page it dont add in home page ?image1  at end